# Python Machine Learing - Find a particular pattern of Time Series Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, find, pattern-matching

I want to train certain patterns of time series data and extract similar patterns from real measurement data.

[Training Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZ8C.jpg)
Training data is in the above format and is more than 50 csv files. [about 500 rows x 4 cols]

[Training Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eifeP.jpg)
I have 4 elements of data(Speed, Angle, Torque, Diff), and I want to create final training data based on the correlation of the factors.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7vKb.jpg)

Previously, I've tried cosine similarity with only one element(Angle) and one training data, but it was limited.

I really want to know how to learn the data when there are multiple training data files and 4 elements.

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.